# How can BIRT be extended

Tags: eclipse, birt

How to add a new option or user interface to retrieve a large dataset(say 1 Million records) and randomly select a few records from the large dataset and run the query on fewer number of records.

Comment: The idea to select a large dataset and then to randomyly select a few records seems very strange to me. Why would you want to do that? It will have terrible performance if you have to retrieve 1 Million records over the network from the DB to the machine where BIRT is running.

It makes much more sense to let the DB randomly select only a few records. For example, with Oracle you could just add a condition `where rownum<=10` to select only 10 rows. However, these rows will not be truly random.

Comment: Firstly,I actually want to give query predictions for a non-technical user. So by running query on fewer records non-technical user would decide whether to run it on large dataset or else try with other predicted queries. Nextly,can't I come up with something which brings fair randomness among the records to be selected?

Comment: So you want your user to run the report twice? First in a kind of quick preview mode, then with the full results? For randomness, you MUST still seek for a solution with SQL. Think about it: if the random selection of records would occur in BIRT, then still ALL records had to be transferred and buffered in BIRT. It would be too slooooooow.

Comment: I agree that it would be slow.Delay in records getting buffered is not an issue. I just wanted to know the ways of extending BIRT's functionality.